# How to add markup percentage to cost price in Magento?

Tags: price, import, catalog-price-rules

Our customer is looking to supply only costs prices and markup percentage for products on Magento. For example if the product cost price is £100 and markup is 20%. He would like to import £100 and 20% into Magento rather than £120.

Is it possible? If yes, how do we import markup in Magento import CSV?

Comment: Magento helpdesk problem which belongs over in magento.stackexchange. There's a module for that in Magento Connect.

Comment: I'm also interested in this.
My idea is to save a percentage margin in the new attribute of the product but I'm not sure where I should add a function to calculate the price when importing so that it is also saved in the database. Any help or idea is appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would fit your case but as far as I know the only way to do this with default Magento functionality is to add a product `custom option` which price is set to 20%.

Add a custom option called **markup** and make it a required checkbox, add one option only or two if markup is not required and give it a *percentage* price of 20%.

On how to do this with your type of import I'm not sure. Not very experienced with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way to do it, but this could be done extremely easily.

Add another attribute called `price_cost`, then create a module that hooks onto the product save observer, that merely takes the cost price attribute value and multiplies it as necessary, then sets the price based on this.